# Search messages in Request Tracker

Tags: request-tracker

In request-tracker, there is a search box in the top-right corner. When entering a word, request tracker searches the subjects of the tickets for the word entered. Is there a way to make RT search the body of the message or the entire thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this entry in the settings:

> %FullTextSearch
>
> Full text search (FTS) without database indexing is a very slow operation, and is thus disabled by default.
>
> Before setting Indexed to 1, read docs/full_text_indexing.pod for the full details of FTS on your particular database.
>
> It is possible to enable FTS without database indexing support, simply by setting the Enable key to 1, while leaving Indexed set to 0. This is not generally suggested, as unindexed full-text searching can cause severe performance problems.

It can be enabled in RT_SiteConfig.pm

Answer (score 2):

There are additional instructions for enabling full text searching in your database available [in the documentation](https://bestpractical.com/docs/rt/4.2/full_text_indexing.html).

Note that when you enable the FullTextSearch option above, it also adds a "Content" option to the ticket search page so you can search from there as well.

The full functionality of the Search box is described on the Simple Search page found at Search > Tickets > Simple Search (in RT 4.2). You can see an example in [the public RT issue tracker](https://issues.bestpractical.com/Search/Simple.html).